# How to get submitted form ID using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit

I'm building a single page web site with multiple forms scattered around it.
I'm using Requirejs and jQuery and I'm trying to minimize the validation process to a single scrip, as so:

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
var empty_fields = [];
  $(this > "chck").each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length !=0 ) {
        return;
  }else{
    empty_fields.push($(this).attr('name'))
    $(this).css('border','2px solid red');
    event.preventDefault();}
})
    if(empty_fields){
        alert("The required field "+empty_fields+" is missing")
    }

});
```

Now the problem is that whenever I'm submitting a form (it doesn't matter which form) the function goes through all the child elements with "chck" (check) class.

What I've tried to do is to force the function to select ONLY the submitted form and check its child (".chck) and them only - Not the rest of the "chck" in other forms.

But I just can't seem to make it refer only to the form being submitted.

Any advice?

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has nothing to do with that plugin.

Comment: Sorry about that - My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the forms id, which is submitted with `event.currentTarget.id`

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
var empty_fields = [];
  $("#" + event.currentTarget.id + " .chck").each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length !=0 ) {
        return;
  }else{
    empty_fields.push($(this).attr('name'))
    $(this).css('border','2px solid red');
    event.preventDefault();}
})
    if(empty_fields){
        alert("The required field "+empty_fields+" is missing")
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but the code you gave will select the submit button and not the form itself.

Comment: No it selects the form. Try it before jumping into conclusions

Comment: Yup, I've tried to nest the form and mixed your code with another one I've been trying. your solution works just fine - Thanx!